# Website randomly downloading html files to visitors

Tags: nginx

Another behaviour I found on a website with malware issues.

It keeps downloading random files like one named s2bbGoEJ.html to users computers. It actually tried to automatically download one such file on my own computer. This looks like a 0 byte file.

How do I go about finding this malware and removing it. This has brought our business to knees and we need desperate help.

Edit: I have tried every Linux scanner I could find (ClamAV, rkhunter and couple more) with no luck whatsoever.

Drupal 7.91, Centos 8, PHP 7.2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Web servers do not download a file, unless the web browser requests the file.  This is the nature of HTTP(S) protocol.  The first step to diagnosing this is to figure out what is causing the user's web browser to request these random files.

Comment: Thanks - is it possible that my browser or personal computer is compromised too. I can confirm that my browser requested (as you say) a file while just browsing pages and my server provided it as a download instead of opening it despite being an HTML file.

Comment: As mentioned on your previous questions, there is no indication, yet, that your server is compromised. If this is affecting your business, then random strangers on this site are going to be of little help. You need someone to actually look at the situation.

Comment: If you opened https://security.stackexchange.com/ and it tried to download a file named s2bbGoEJ.html while the page opened, this won't be an indication of a virus or malware? This file s2bbGoEJ.html is NOT hosted on my server nor it is the intended purpose. Someone planted it to distribute malware.

Comment: That's a BIG assumption based solely on the fact that it is unexpected. It is ***obviously*** not malware. You need to stop jumping ahead of the facts. And yes, I have visited sites that has a simple misconfiguration that ended up downloading random 0byte files. Non-maliciously.

Comment: I like your enthusiasm in shooting it down but same codebase has existed for years and suddenly random files are downloading and http version gets redirected to spam sites.

Comment: @JMJohn WRT 'is it possible that my browser or personal computer is compromised too?' - have you tried doing the same with a different browser on a different device?  If so, do you see the same behavior?

Comment: @mti2935 It's not easy to reproduce but checking by Google analytics, a few other people are finding 404s for those weird HTML files as well.

Comment: @JMJohn, then the most likely explanation is that a page on your site that you surf to first (such as your home page) is infected, with references to these random pages.  Try to identify the first page, then look at the source of this page to see if anything looks malicious.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out a hacked Memcached installation. They took control of memcached server and changed the file permissions/security settings on files folder and executed scripts from there.